# Why it is possible to ommit parameter in expressions like .map(println)?

Tags: scala, syntax

I have a list of strings

```
val myStrings = List("One", "Two", "Three")
```

I want to check if the list contains a string I do.

```
myStrings.exists("One".contains)
```

I get this from googling. But I want to understand it.

I see you can do `"One".contains("O")`

to check `One` contains `O` that makes sense. But I don't get how no paramaters when passed to myStrings.exists works.

What I am missing?

Comment: Actually what you're checking is that some string from `myStrings` has the same character as "One". This one will be true as well: `val myStrings = List("n"); myStrings.exists("One".contains)`

Comment: From your description, I think you want `myStrings.contains("One")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is shorthand, or "syntactic sugar".

I'm sure you've seen `List("A","B").foreach(println)`.

This is the same, you do not need to specify the parameter if there is only one.

So `myStrings.exists("One".contains)` is shorthand for

```
myStrings.exists("One" contains _)
```

Which in itself is shorthand for the full function literal

```
myStrings.exists(x => "One" contains x)
```

Note that this does not check whether your list `contains` the `String` "One", it checks whether your `List` contains a `String` that is *contained within* "One".

You probably just want the `contains` method on `List`.

Also note that `contains` on `List` is O(n). The same method on `Set` is O(1) - i.e. constant time.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a Function1 to a function or method that *expects* a Function1, you can omit the underscore.

`List#foreach` expects a `Function1[X,Unit]`, so you can say `myList.foreach(println)` instead of `myList.foreach(println(_))` or `myList.foreach(x => println(x))`.

Similarly:

```
scala> val xs = List("a","b","c")
xs: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val set = Set("c","d","e")
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(c, d, e)

scala> xs.filter(set.contains)
res0: List[String] = List(c)
```